# How to get a value of a column which is inserted by radioButton to another form using SqlDataReader class in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a column in my table which is empPerm which spesify the permission of an employee there are two possible values that can be inserted to this column and they are: Manager or Employee, one of these values inserted when registering employee using radioButtons using these codes

```
try
{
    if (mangPermrdb.Checked == true)
    {
        getPerm = "Manager";
    }
    else
    {
        getPerm = "Employee";
    }

    cn.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into emp(empName, empAdd, empBdate, empPhone1, empPhone2, empSSN, empEmail, empQualf, empPass, empPerm) values ('" + empRegNametxt.Text + "','" + empRegAddtxt.Text + "', '" + empRegBdatePicker.Value + "', '" + empRegPhone1txt.Text + "', '" + empRegPhone2txt.Text + "'," + empRegSSNtxt.Text +" ,'" + empRegEmailtxt.Text + "','" + empRegQualftxt.Text + "','" + empRegPasstxt.Text + "','"+getPerm+"')", cn);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Employee registered in the pharmacy system successfully");              
}
```

How to  read the empPerm (employee permission) for a specific employee into the radioButton of the same text of the value ? any help!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: what kind of type is empPerm in your SQL DB? YOu need simple select command then put in DataTable and parse it in your C# model class representation of your DB Table

Answer (score 0):

Do a select on empPerm:

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select empPerm from emp where id = <insert your id here>", cn))
    using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(cmd))
        if (dr.Read())
            managerradiobutton.Checked = dr.GetString(0) == "Manager";
```